# Google Page Speed in Fx doesn't show "Paint Snapshots" option; alternatives?

Tags: performance, rendering, pagespeed

For some reason Google Page Speed, the add-on to Firebug, doesn't show the "Paint Snapshots" option as seen on http://code.google.com/speed/articles/browser-paint-events.html

I've tried this with the latest version of Page Speed on Fx 7.0.1 with Firebug 1.8.3 and Fx 5.0.1 with Firebug 1.8.0. Both to no avail.

My question is thus: what am I missing here? If it just isn't in anymore (all docs I can find are about Fx 3.x I believe), is there other software that does the same? That is, showing in fairly slow motion how a page is rendered, which assets are shown first, etc. For an example of what I'm looking for, click "Play Paint Events" at the URL above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this [feature was removed in an earlier version of Page Speed](http://groups.google.com/group/page-speed-discuss/browse_thread/thread/152dc6e1b7726e76?pli=1):

> In the upcoming Page Speed 1.9 release, we will be removing the Page
>   Speed Activity panel. At the time of launch, Page Speed Activity
>   provided information unavailable in other tools like Firebug, such as
>   accurate DNS lookup timing, TCP connection timing, and JavaScript
>   parse/execution timing. As of Firefox 3.6, Firebug and other tools are
>   able to access the same DNS/TCP/network timing information as the Page
>   Speed Activity panel, and Firebug now displays this information in its
>   net panel. Thus, we have decided to remove the activity panel from
>   Page Speed since it duplicates information found in other popular
>   tools.
>
> Page Speed Activity also provided JavaScript parse and execution
>   timing. However, in recent releases of Firefox, there was a noticeable
>   "observer effect" when profiling JavaScript parse and execution, which
>   made this timing information invalid.
>
> Going forward, we recommend using an existing network waterfall tool
>   such as Firebug, HTTPWatch, Speed Tracer, or Chrome Developer Tools to
>   gather HTTP waterfall charts. Page Speed will continue to focus on
>   providing specific performance suggestions to make your sites faster.
>
> Thank you, Bryan and the Page Speed team

I don't know of a suitable replacement for the Play Paint Events capability. As Andy Davies mentioned, webpagetest.org does have a "video record" feature which captures the page as it's being drawn, but perhaps not at the detail this tool used to have.

Comment: Brian, I know this is an old question, but I need a Firefox tool similar to Chrome timeline and can't find anything. Specifically, we developed an inertial scroller, it is very fast on Galaxy S2,  but too slow on ZTE Open on Firefox OS. With Chrome Dev tools timeline we first optimized on the desktop and then used it in a remote mode to optimize in Chrome on Android. Now need to do a similar thing in Firefox. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

webpagetest.org can do a similar sort of thing